# Do not copy all files when pip install

Tags: python, pip

When I make `pip install .`, it takes too much time.  I need to do it from time to time (it's my local repo).
But I have the large `TrashScripts` folder (~ 10GB) inside my package.
My git repo doesn't have lots of files inside that folder. But sometimes I gather logs, download a lot of files, etc.

Suppose, my package has name `MyPackage`. It has the following structure:

```
--MyPackage
  --MyPackage 
    --module
    --module1
    --bins
  --TrashScripts
    --folder1
    --folder2
    --folder3
  setup.py
  requirements.txt
  MANIFEST.in
```

MANIFEST.in is the following:

```
graft MyPackage 
    include bins/some.dat
```

PRUNE word in MANIFEST didn't work. 
When I use `-v` parameter (for `pip install .`), it shows me that the first command is creating a temporary folder with copying `TrashScripts` folder (and everything inside it!).

How can I prevent `pip install .` from copying all files from `TrashScripts` folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have your repo locally you can make an **[editable install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs)**:

```
pip install -e .
```

This will only put a reference to your local folder into the Python site-packages folder and no data is copied. You can even continue editing and there is no need ever to reinstall the package.